# help with oracle sql case statement using count criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, case

So far, this query works using exists:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
                   ( SELECT *
                     FROM TEST1
                     WHERE timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
                   )
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
       END AS FLG
FROM dual
```

Now, I need to add another criteria.
Since my data has these consistent count values of 100 for example:

```
SQL> select count(*), timestamp from TEST1 group by timestamp order by 2 desc;

  COUNT(*)  TIMESTAMP
---------- ----------
      100 2.0111E+11
      100 2.0111E+11
```

I now need to alter this query so that I get only those that have a count(*) of `100`
and if they do then set my flag = 0 and if not set my flag =1.

I'm not sure where to add this count criteria value of 100. Can I still use CASE for this?

Comment: You need to look into the HAVING clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try looking into the `having`-statement:

```
select count(*), timestamp
from TEST1
group by timestamp
having count(*) = 100
```

Basically it's the same as `where`, but only for aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT *
                 FROM TEST1
                 WHERE timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
               ) 
            and 
               DECODE(( SELECT count(*)
                 FROM TEST1
                 WHERE timestamp = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd') || '0000'
               ),100,true,false)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
   END AS FLG
FROM dual
```